# How many subsets of $S$ exactly of size $3$ must one have in order to know that at least two of our subsets have same weight?

Tags: combinatorics

Let $S$ be a set $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$.

How many subsets of $S$ exactly of size $3$ must one have in order to know that at least two of our subsets have same weight? (= sum of the numbers in the subset)?

My try:
We will have $\ _{10}C_3 = 120$ subsets which will have size $3$.

I don't know how to proceed further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to *avoid* having two subsets of the same weight, you can proceed as follows to produce a large collection. Start with $X=\{1,2,3\}$ and add it to you collection. Now as long as $X\neq\{8,9,10\}$ there must be a value $x\in X$ with $x+1\in S$ but $x+1\notin X$ (prove this). Now replace $x$ by $x+1$ in $X$, add the result to your collection of subsets, and repeat.

Finally prove that the collection of subsets you've obtained that avoids having the same weight twice has the largest possible size for such a collection. (The points I left to do are quite easy to fill in.)

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$n$ is the weight of some subset of size $3$ if and only if $n$ is element of $\{k\in\mathbb N\mid6\leq k\leq27\}$.

Apparantly there are $22$ *different* weights.

Comment: So, the answer should be 23 right? because we can have 22 different weights and from 23rd turn we will have a duplication.

Comment: Yes. That is a direct consequence.